# How can I update my Choice box everytime other choice box changes?

Tags: java, awt

so I have this problem... I have 2 choice boxes, the first one contains guitar brands, and the second one the type of guitars that brand has. I am using an Item Listener and it works, the only problem is that it keeps adding. For example: I select 2 times the same brand, it will write 2 times the type of guitar, and I just want the types of guitars. How can I fix this? Here's my code of the listener:

```java
private class ItemHandler implements ItemListener {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        try {
            if(event.getSource() == choice_GuitarBrand) {
                /*I have a guitar array that will fetch the associated ID of the selected
                item given the name */
                int id = cmd.fetchGuitarID(choice_GuitarBrand.getSelectedItem());
                for(Guitar g : cmd.getSpecificGuitar(id)) {
                    choice_TypeOfGuitar.add(g.getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is the `choice_TypeOfGuitar` object?

Comment: it's the choice box; Choice choice_TypeOfGuitar = new Choice(); I want to put the name of the guitars of the specific brand in that choice box. So I fetch the ID from an array of guitars and if the brand name equals to that brand name it returns the guitar ID. then th cmd.geSpecificGuitar(id) will return an array with the types of guitar of that brand. And then I try to add the name of the guitar type to that choice box

Comment: See my updated answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the objects in the list before adding new ones:

```java
private class ItemHandler implements ItemListener {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        try {
            if(event.getSource() == choice_GuitarBrand) {
                /*I have a guitar array that will fetch the associated ID of the selected
                item given the name */
                int id = cmd.fetchGuitarID(choice_GuitarBrand.getSelectedItem());
                choice_TypeOfGuitar.removeAll(); // see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html#removeAll()
                for(Guitar g : cmd.getSpecificGuitar(id)) {
                    choice_TypeOfGuitar.add(g.getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```